# What does it mean to 'hash cons'?

Tags: performance, algorithm, optimization, scala, hash

When to use it and why?

My question comes from the sentence: "hash cons with some classes and compare their instances with reference equality"

Comment: You're going to need to be a lot more specific to get an answer.  Is there a language involved, can you point to a link, etc ...

Comment: seems to be a lisp/scheme thing - cons is the list constructor

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Neil, because I was lost

Comment: to the questioner - assuming this is  alisp/scheme question - add relevant tags and preferably modify your title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting everyone's answers together:

> ACL2 (A Computational Logic for Applicative Common Lisp) is a software system consisting of a programming language, an extensible theory in a first-order logic, and a mechanical theorem prover.
>
> -- [Wiki ACL2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL2)
>
> In computer programming, cons (pronounced /ˈkɒnz/ or /ˈkɒns/) is a fundamental function in most dialects of the Lisp programming language. cons constructs (hence the name) memory objects which hold two values or pointers to values. These objects are referred to as (cons) cells, conses, or (cons) pairs. In Lisp jargon, the expression "to cons x onto y" means to construct a new object with (cons x y). The resulting pair has a left half, referred to as the car (the first element), and a right half (the second element), referred to as the cdr.
>
> -- [Wiki Cons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons)
>
> Logically, hons is merely another name for cons, i.e., the following is an ACL2 theorem:
>
> (equal (hons x y) (cons x y))
>
> Hons generally runs slower than cons because in creating a hons, an attempt is made to see whether a hons already exists with the same car and cdr. This involves search and the use of hash-tables.
>
> -- [http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/acl2/current/HONS.html](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/%7Emoore/acl2/current/HONS.html)

Given your question:

> hash cons with some classes and compare their instances with reference equality

It appears that `hash cons` is the process of hashing a LISP constructor to determine if an object already exists via equality comparison.

Answer (score 4):

From Odersky, Spoon and Venners (2007), *Programming in Scala*, Artima Press, p. 243:

You hash cons instances of a class by caching all instances you have created in a weak collection. Then, any time you want a new instance of the class, you first check the cache. If the cache already has an element equal to the one you are about to create, you can reuse the existing instance. As a result of this arrangement, any two instances that are equal with equals() are also equal with reference equality.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_cons now redirects.

It is [`con`s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons) with hashing to allow `eq` (reference) comparison instead of a deep one. This is more efficient for memory (because identical objects are stored as references), and is of course faster if comparison is a common operation.

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/acl2/current/HONS.html describes an implementation for Lisp.